# connection java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, database-connection

I am trying to add some bunch of records in MySQL database usign jdbc in java. This program works absolutely fine for 100 records. But after 100 records i get following error.

```
Exception occured while obtaining 

connectionjava.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.rest.EmployeeRest.insertDesigMySQLData(EmployeeRest.java:446)
    at com.rest.EmployeeRest.syncDesignation(EmployeeRest.java:188)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:442)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1082)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:623)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

After google about this error, someone tell to use telnet command on localhost 3306(MySQL port). and it gives me "Too many connections" error.
Can anyone help me to solve this issue.

API code to get Data and add to MySQL:

```
ArrayList<Employee> arrDesig = getAllDesig();
setTotRecords(arrDesig.size());
System.out.println("Oracle TotRecords = "+getTotRecords());
if(arrDesig.size() > 0){
    for(int iCnt=0; iCnt<arrDesig.size(); iCnt++){
        if(insertDesigMySQLData(arrDesig.get(iCnt)) == 1){
            mysqlDat++;
        }
        System.out.println("MySQL inserted data = "+mysqlDat);
    }
    if(getTotRecords() == mysqlDat){
        retval = 1;
    }else{
        retval = 0;
    }
}else{
    retval = 0;
}
```

MySQL code to add:

```
int retval = 0;
    OracleDataSource objMySQLDataSource = new OracleDataSource("mysql");
    try{
        Connection connection = objMySQLDataSource.getDbConnection();
        CallableStatement pstmt=connection.prepareCall("{call addDesig(?,?,?)}");
        pstmt.setString(1,objEmployee.getDesig_id());
        System.out.println("getDesig_id() = "+objEmployee.getDesig_id());
        pstmt.setString(2,objEmployee.getDesig_nm());
        System.out.println("getDesig_nm() = "+objEmployee.getDesig_nm());
        pstmt.registerOutParameter(3, Types.NUMERIC);
        pstmt.executeUpdate();
        retval = pstmt.getInt(3);
        pstmt.close();
    }catch (Exception e) {
        retval = 0;
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        objMySQLDataSource.connectionClose();
    }
    return retval;
```

Oracle Connection

```
OracleDataSource(){
    setUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@dburl");
    setDriver("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
    setUserName("admin");
    setPassword("**********");
}
```

MySQL Connection

```
OracleDataSource(String mysql){
    setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/academicdb?verifyServerCertificate=false&useSSL=true&useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC");
    setDriver("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");//com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    setUserName("root");
    setPassword("");
}

public Connection getDbConnection() {
        Connection con = null;
        try{
            Class.forName(getDriver());
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(getUrl(), getUserName(), getPassword());
        } catch (Exception se) {
            System.out.println("Exception occured while obtaining connection" + se.toString());
        }
        return con;
    }
```

Comment: restart you mysql Server. Also Show the relevant code

Comment: So basically I am calling REST API which will add employees from Oracle to MYSQL table. I am using one ArrayList which will first get all employee details from oracle database. Then I am adding those records in MySQL one by one. Meantime I am calling one more API which will ping me about this syncing progress.i.e. 5%,16% etc.

Comment: Which library did you use for OracleDataSource class?

Comment: Are you really using Oracle driver to insert into MySQL database?

Comment: Why are you trying to use `OracleDataSource` to connect to MySQL? And please make sure to include the full exception stacktrace of that `SQLNonTransientConnectionException`.

Comment: I am using ojdbc6 for Oracle and mysql-connector-java-8.0 libraries for connection.

Comment: Could you please add code for `connectionClose()`? According to your code you open one connection in constructor of `OracleDataSource` and one when calling `getDbConnection`. So looks like you do not close half of your connections to MySQL database. Then you reach limit of 100 opened connections on your MySQL server and get error

Comment: @Ivan You right. I just discovered that and fixed that code. Now I am calling connection in getDbConnection() method only.

Comment: Is there any limit set for connections in MySQL? and can we change it?

Comment: Not sure that there is a way to change that limit. But you can use connection pools to limit amount of simultaneous connections